# Yealink T48S upgrade/downgrade issues

Tags: networking, sip, phone

So I’ve been using the T48S on the Skype for Business firmware for a while now (I purchased it second hand on eBay and it came with version 66.9.0.45)

I originally flashed it to 66.81.0.70 lync version when I got it so I could mess with a SIP server. I eventually got bored and flashed it back to 66.9.0.80.

Now many months down the line I want to flash it back to lync version (latest is 66.85.0.5) so I attempted to flash it.

And my the second I start flashing the device it cuts out says UGRADING FIRMWARE. then instead of moving to another splash screen saying something along the lines, it reboots and starts initializing.

Then it boots back to 66.9.0.80.

And I can’t seem to flash it to anything else but 66.9.0.89.

I’ve tried almost every lync firmware.

I am not too sure what I’m doing wrong, open to suggestions! I greatly need help on this matter :)

Comment: How do you flash it ? TFTP usually works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem my device is stuck between fw .80 and .89. I'm in contact with Yealink support. Until now it's probably a bug or limitation.

I suggest downgrading gradually to older Lync/SfB Firmware, and then reporting the issue to Yealink support.